# Media Query to differentiate Google Pixel 1/2 vs Google Pixel XL vs Google Pixel 2 XL

Tags: android, media-queries, google-pixel

Im writing a cordova app and need to isolate these google phones to adjust styling

given this:

[image]

Im struggling to differentiate between any of the Google Pixel Phones.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 411px) and (max-width: 731px) {
    .myDiv{ background-color: blue; }
}
```

this triggers on all Pixels - both in emulators and physical devices

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 411px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .myDiv{ background-color: blue; }
}
```

this does not trigger at all with any pixel phone - dosnt matter if 3 or 4 pixel ratio

```
@media screen and (device-width: 411px) and (device-height: 731px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6){
   .myDiv{ background-color: blue;
}
```

this also does not trigger on any pixel phone

im struggling to find even ONE media query that works for isolating the Google Pixel 2 XL - nothing seems to have been posted - but the phone has been out for a while?

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: Did you have any luck on this? I have the same problem

Comment: i have not unfortunatley :( - seems like SO questions get buried REAL quick nowadays - wonder if something changed.

Comment: what i ended up doing is calculating device height with JS and attaching variables to css classes to push and pull div elements based on height.... not pretty but works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a devices width, height, and [pixel aspect ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) using Javascript.

### Output Device Information Function

```
function OutputDeviceInformation() {
  let deviceWidth = window.screen.width;
  let deviceHeight = window.screen.height;
  let devicePixelAspectRation = window.devicePixelRatio;

  console.log('Width: ' + deviceWidth);
  console.log('Height: ' + deviceHeight);
  console.log('Pixel Aspect Ratio: ' + devicePixelAspectRatio);
}
```

### Google Pixel 2 XL Output:

Width: 412px

Height: 823px

Pixel Aspect Ratio: 3.5

### Media Query to target Google Pixel 2 XL

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 412px) 
  and (device-height: 823px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 412px) 
  and (device-height: 823px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Target Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 412px) 
  and (device-height: 823px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this for Google Pixel XL :

/*Google Pixel XL */
 '@media screen and (device-width: 411px) and (device-height: 823px){

}'