# What is media query for nexus 7 and pixel 2?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm creating Ionic 4 Angular app, this app run near about 4 to 5 devices. now i'm unable to find perfect media query for nexus 7 and pixel 2. give me some suggestion or media query for this 2 dives ?
below shows which media query i'm using.

> ------------------------------------------------google nexus 7-----------------------------------------------------
>   @media screen and (min-device-width : 601px) and (max-device-width :970px) {}
>
> -------------------------------------------------------pixel 2---------------------------------------------------------
>   @media screen and (min-device-width : 411px) and (max-device-width :731px) {}

Comment: perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/12596624/4718434 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269170/4718434 ?

Comment: before post this question i was trying above 2 link solution also. but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Creating media queries for specific devices will not make your application future proof. There are simply too many devices out there and the moment you ship your application there will be new ones. 
Start with a design that looks good on a very small device and then add media queries when you notice items get too wide.